# How to send the exact edited text using CKEditor

Tags: php, email, ckeditor

I have created a contact me page that uses CK Editor to edit the content of the mail. I am using xampp/ localhost to test the mail. I want the mail to be exactly like i edit it in the editor

For example the bold part in editor doesnot show up bold in the mail it is sent as

```
<strong>SOMETHING IN BOLD</strong>
```

How do i use CK editor or any other so that the mail is sent as

**SOMETHING IN BOLD**

and not as shown above.

Thank you.

HTML Code

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" style="height:100%">

                <input name="articleTitle" value="Title" maxlength="50" 
                id="articleTitle">

                <textarea name="article-body">
                    Compose your article...
                </textarea>

            <script>
                CKEDITOR.inline( 'article-body' );
            </script>

        <br>
                <input name="senderName" type="text" value="Name" maxlength="50" 
                id="name" class="textBox">

                <input name="senderEmail" value="Email address" maxlength="50" 
                id="email" class="textBox">

                <input name="abtyou" value="About Yourself" maxlength="150" 
                id="abtyou" class="textBox">

                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button">

            </form>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php

    $thankYou="";   

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $recipient="zain.farid@live.com";
    $subject="New Guest Post";
    $sender=$_POST["senderName"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $senderAbout=$_POST["abtyou"];
    $message=$_POST["article-body"];
    $title=$_POST["articleTitle"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nAbout Sender: $senderAbout\nTitle: $title\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

    $thankYou="Thank you! Your post has been submitted.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not sending an HTML-header with the email. Here you can see how you can do this: (example 3) http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    // ... email settings ...

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $sender <$senderEmail>" . "\r\n";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, $headers);

    // ...
}

?>
```